# Concatenate Random Result with Where Condition

Tags: sqlite, union

I want to concatenate results of 2 Select Queries from the same table;

my table :

```
CREATE TABLE "books" (
"id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
"book_title"    TEXT UNIQUE,
"Book_desc" TEXT,
"category"  TEXT)
```

The first Query :`Select * from books where id = 2`

The second Query :`Select * from books where id != 2 order by random() limit 3`

I want the the id=3 to be the first row in results, I tried so many Union queries but It didn't work.

Here is what I did so far :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ee515/3

Comment: Do those queries on their own act as expected?

Comment: Would it be ok to have another value in the output, like a 1 for the first query and a 2 for everything from the second? Or would you want to hide that backstage magic?

Comment: Yes the 2 queries are working well,  and better if intermediary variable are hidden in the output

Comment: Did you manage to make a union of those (one without the desired order of course)? Please show that query. Also, to complete your [mre], please show a few lines of `create table ...` and `insert ...` to provide a foundation for solutions.

Comment: Ok , I will Edit my Question with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd query to get 50 random rows without the row of `id=100` should be:

```
select *
from (select * from table1 where id <> 100  order by random() limit 50)
```

So use `UNION ALL` and conditional sorting:

```
select *
from (
  select * from table1 where id = 100
  union all
  select *
  from (select * from table1 where id <> 100  order by random() limit 50) 
)
order by id = 100 desc
```

Comment: Better than my idea, which would even have added undesired value.